# Not able to set the "PasswordNeverExpires" parameter to true in Powershell 2.0

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-2.0

Below is my Powershell script -

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$objOU=[ADSI]“LDAP://OU=Service,OU=Accounts,DC=xyz,DC=com”;
$dataSource=import-csv “add_user2.csv”;

foreach($dataRecord in $datasource) 
{
$cn=$dataRecord.FirstName + ” ” + $dataRecord.LastName
$sAMAccountName=$dataRecord.FirstName + “.” + $dataRecord.LastName
$givenName=$dataRecord.FirstName
$sn=$dataRecord.LastName

$displayName=$sn + “, ” + $givenName
$userPrincipalName=$sAMAccountName + “@test.com”;

#Additional Attributes
$objUser=$objOU.Create(“user”,”CN=”+$cn)
$objUser.Put(“sAMAccountName”,$sAMAccountName)
$objUser.Put(“userPrincipalName”,$userPrincipalName)
$objUser.Put(“displayName”,$displayName)
$objUser.Put(“givenName”,$givenName)
$objUser.Put(“sn”,$sn)

#Place the additional attributes into the record

$objUser.Put("PasswordNeverExpires", $true)
$objUser.SetInfo()

}
```

I am trying to set the values of an ActiveDirectory user, using the above script. The problem I am facing is I am not able set the "PasswordNeverExpires" attribute under Account Options in Account tab to True.

My input file "add_user1.csv" looks like -

```
FirstName   LastName
Test              Account1
```

Will appreciate all help.

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another thing you could use to get around having to fiddle with the UserAccountControl property is to use the `PasswordNeverExpires` parameter of `Set-ADUser`.

```
$objUser | Set-ADUser -PasswordNeverExpires
```

In fact, you could replace a lot of that code by using `New-ADUser`

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$dataSource=import-csv “add_user2.csv”;

foreach($dataRecord in $datasource) 
{
    $cn=$dataRecord.FirstName + ” ” + $dataRecord.LastName
    $sAMAccountName=$dataRecord.FirstName + “.” + $dataRecord.LastName
    $givenName=$dataRecord.FirstName
    $sn=$dataRecord.LastName
    $displayName=$sn + “, ” + $givenName
    $userPrincipalName=$sAMAccountName + “@test.com”;

    New-ADUser $cn -SamAccountName $sAMAccountName -GivenName $givenName `
        -Surname $sn -DisplayName $displayName -UserPrincipalName $userPrincipalName `
        -PasswordNeverExpires $true -Path "OU=Service,OU=Accounts,DC=rjfdev,DC=com"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no PasswordNeverExpires property. If you run `Get-Member` on `$objUser` you will see this. These properties are controlled by UserAccountControl. For more information [look here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305144).

[This blog article](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4231.working-with-active-directory-using-powershell-adsi-adapter.aspx) details how to set the password never expires attribute to true:

```
Setting "Password never expire" attribute on user object 
This property unlike many other properties of AD object are contained in bitmask
attribute UserAccountControl 
(not related in any way with User Account Control feature of Windows). 
To set it you need to retrieve current value of this attribute and use binary OR
operation (-bor) to calculate new value.


$User = [ADSI]"LDAP://cn=Gusev,ou=Users,ou=Lab,dc=contoso,dc=com"
$UAC = $User.UserAccountControl[0] -bor 65536
$User.Put("userAccountControl",$UAC)
$User.SetInfo()
```

Your script needs to be modified as such:

```
$objUser.SetInfo()

#Place the additional attributes into the record
$UAC = $objUser.UserAccountControl[0] -bor 65536
$objUser.Put("userAccountControl",$UAC)
$objUser.SetInfo()
```

Without running `SetInfo()` twice the script will throw an error.